# javascript code repeated when using ascx control

Tags: c#, web, charts, fusioncharts

I have a FusionCharts library that I want to use to chart within a C# web application.
The code to create a chart (after locating some overhead files in a separate folder) is:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Charts/FusionCharts.js">

  <script type="text/javascript"><!--         

  var myChart = new FusionCharts( "Charts/Spline.swf", 
  "myChartId", "400", "300", "0");
  myChart.setXMLUrl("Data.xml");
  myChart.render("chartContainer");

  // -->     
  </script>
```

Now what I tried to do is to include that piece of code within a user control. But I would like to have the option to pass it some parameters such as the "Data.xml" that I want it to use and height and width.
I have it working right now, but my current problem is when I include more than one instance of the control in the page because if I check my "View Source" code for my project page, it adds alright the two components but the javascript looks like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Charts/FusionCharts.js">

  <script type="text/javascript"><!--         

  var myChart = new FusionCharts( "Charts/Spline.swf", 
  "myChartId", "400", "300", "0");
  myChart.setXMLUrl("Data.xml");
  myChart.render("chartContainer");

  // -->     
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="Charts/FusionCharts.js">

  <script type="text/javascript"><!--         

  var myChart = new FusionCharts( "Charts/Spline.swf", 
  "myChartId", "400", "300", "0");
  myChart.setXMLUrl("Data.xml");
  myChart.render("chartContainer");

  // -->     
  </script>
```

It duplicates the code, so my variable myChart, gets duplicated and as expected, only one chart is rendered.
What is the best way to get around this? Or basically include JavaScript that is dynamically generated in the page_load that I can manipulate for each control?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include the FusionCharts.js script only once per page, then register it with `RegisterClientScriptInclude` in `OnPreRender`:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
        typeof(YourUserControl), "FusionCharts", "Charts/FusionCharts.js");
}
```

For the other script block, please clarify how it should work. Is `myChart` the only thing that should be different? What about `"myChartId"` and `"chartContainer"`?

If the problem is solely that the `myChart` variables are conflicting with each other, then you could enclose your script in a self-executing anonymous function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
(function() {
    var myChart = new FusionCharts( "Charts/Spline.swf", 
        "<%= this.ChartId %>", "400", "300", "0");
        myChart.setXMLUrl("<%= this.DataFile %>");
        myChart.render("<%= this.ChartContainerId %> ");
})();
// -->     
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the OnPreRender tip, I'll try that out. On the other items, yes, myChartId, 400, 300, Data.xml, and chartContainer need to change in a controlled way, say:

Comment: For example if I include two user controls in my aspx page I would like each of the codes to look like

`var myChart1 = new FusionCharts( "Charts/Spline.swf", 
        "myChartId1", "400", "300", "0");
        myChart1.setXMLUrl("Data1.xml");
        myChart1.render("chartContainer1"); `
and 

 `var myChart2 = new FusionCharts( "Charts/Spline.swf", 
        "myChartId2", "400", "300", "0");
        myChart2.setXMLUrl("Data2.xml");
        myChart2.render("chartContainer2");`

Comment: If your user control declares public properties for the values that can change, then you can use the `<%= ... %>` syntax to insert them into your script.